# Why does this JAVA endpoint not return a detailed error message to the client?

Tags: java, vue.js, error-handling, axios

I have a server in Java. If I intentionally mispell a word in the sql query so that it is invalid, this function throws an appropriate error. Why does this not pass the detailed error message back to the client? Instead, the extent of the error message only includes

> "Request failed with status code 500"

Here is the actual detailed error:

> ERROR: relation "contacs" does not exist

Here is the endpoint...

```
@POST
@Path("{from_list_id}/{to_list_id}")
public Message merge(@PathParam("from_list_id") int from_list_id, @PathParam("to_list_id") int to_list_id) {
    String sql = "select * from lists where list_id=?";

    sql = "insert into contacts (data, imported, list_id) select data, imported," + to_list_id
            + " from contacs where list_id = " + from_list_id;
    int rowsAffected = db.sql(sql).execute().getRowsAffected();
    return Message.success(
            "Successfully merged " + rowsAffected + " contacts");
}
```

I see that dropwizard captures the exact error in my log file but this error does not get sent to the client. Our client is a Vuejs component that uses axios.

Here is the client axios call

```
 this.$axios
    .post("/merge/" + this.from_list_id + "/" + this.to_list_id, {
      timeout: 0
    })
    .then(
      response => {
        this.list = response;
        util.showSuccess(response.data.message);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        util.showError(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: you can use any DTO to propagate the message. `Drawback:- additional complexity`

Comment: Because HTTP status 500 is specifically designed to *conceal* information from the client, so as not to leak attack vectors to attackers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by using `ControllerAdvice` which acts like global Exception handler so you can handle any kind of `Exception` and return what you want

An example showing how to handle all Exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdviceController {

    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleBusinessException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
        //you can return what you want here getCause(), getMessage() etc
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception, 500);
    }
}
```

Although you can return details for all exceptions but you shouldn't do this as it considered as a bad practice. You should handle specific type and return informative message and proper http code